# LINQ OrderBy in an included collection

Tags: c#, linq

I am retrieving a list of `Tickets` and `TicketActivities` via the `.Include(ta => ta.TicketActivities)` which is a reverse navigation property of type `ICollection<TicketActivity>()` on my `Ticket` class.

How can I sort by my tickets by the `SubmitDate` property and the `TicketActivities` by the `DateTime` property?

```
 using (var entityContext = new InformationSystemsContext())
 {
     IQueryable<Ticket> tickets = null;
     tickets = entityContext.Tickets.Include(i => i.TicketActivities)
                                    .OrderBy(t => t.SubmitDate).ThenBy(t => t.TicketActivities.DateTime);
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = (from Ticket in entityContext.Tickets
            join Activity in entityContext.TicketActivities
                on Ticket.ID equals Activity.TicketID into JoinedList // fields you made relationship base on those
            group JoinedList by Ticket into GroupedList
            select new {
                Ticket = GroupedList.Key,
                Activities = GroupedList.OrderBy(u => u.DateTime)
            })
            .OrderBy(u => u.SubmitDate)
            .ToList();
```